# Shrink/Grow animation using jQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

How can a grow/shrink animation be done with jQuery and/or CSS? An example that I can think of is [this](https://www.zaarly.com) when you click on the `Join Now` button.

I looked into [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) but they did not offer such an animation.

Comment: there are a ton of jquery modal plugins available. A little google search will likely turn up "The 30 best modals" or similar. Also known as `dialog`'s

Comment: I have created the modal myself, I'll now like to animate the modal with a 'shrinking' animation.

Comment: easy to implement with jQuery `animate()` method http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Use whatever css properties you want. Also some built in effects like `slideUp()` , `slideDown()`. look into source of a plugin for ideas also.. Effects API: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: I dont see Join now text anywhere in the page

Comment: @defau1t  geeesh..try `ctrl+F`

Comment: @charlietfl: I guess this service is actually not available in my locale. It says coming soon in my area. So thats way Join Now button is not there. I guess..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eYYkS/1/)** — Solution using CSS3's `transition-duration` ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)) and `transform:scale(X,Y);` ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp)).

*Update:*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eYYkS/3/)** — Going a step further, doing more than just changing to `opacity:0;` by adding `display:none;` (via jQuery `.hide()`) at the end of the animation.