# Make a DIV and all children elements smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to re-size a part of HTML in my design.
I need this change to happen as an animation.

The DIV itself and all it's inner elements i.e. Images, Paragraphs, Anchors etc should be re-sized just like when you re-size an image with a constant aspect ratio.

I think, the tool should get current height and width of element and increase/decrease them, but it won't work for texts, actually for a text element you need to change font size.

How can I do this in JS, CSS, HTML?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: `Can this be done in JS, CSS, HTML?` - Yes.

Comment: @DaveZych I'm searching about an hour and found nothing, can you say How?

Comment: well in jQuery `animate` does everything even font-size

Comment: @PRAISER How about `background-image`s?

Comment: @Webinan you were talking about objects, you didn't mention that includes background-image as well, you may manage do that with img instead of using background.

Comment: @PRAISER `just like when you re-size an image with a constant aspect ratio` I said.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use CSS transform:scale

```
.small {
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Opera */
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Firefox */
}
```

**EDIT**: reference/credits: [Shrink/Grow animation using jQuery/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324537/shrink-grow-animation-using-jquery-css)

Comment: `scale(1.2,1.2)` is the same as `scale(1.2)`. Besides that, the OP wants things smaller, not bigger, so should maybe be `scale(0.8)` instead

Comment: Yeah, indeed I saw the sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eYYkS/).

Comment: Thanks, it does the job, you can also improve this answer with IE6+ support using IE filters and this site `http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/`