# how to set next/prev btn size in swiper?

Tags: html, css

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RlGF.jpg)I want to change the size of the prev/next btn icon to make it smaller, how do I do that?

```
 <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
```

```
.swiper .swiper-button-prev,
.swiper .swiper-button-next{
  color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 10;

}
```

Comment: decrease width and height. that would solve the problem. if not then try to explain what problem you are facing and what you expect your button to look like and what's the output you are getting?

Comment: it's still the same, only the background size has changed to be smaller instead of the prev/next icon

Comment: that's 'cause you are changing the width and height of div not the icon what icons you are using?? is it a image or from some website? like fontawesome,heroicon,favicon??

Comment: try to check my post again, there I have added an example image

Comment: i use swiper js

Comment: ohh you are using swiper js>... then read the docs they should have mentioned it somewhere or there is another method just inspect the icon from devtools and see what class those icons are using and set height and width to those class

Comment: easy way here, `.swiper-button-prev::after{
  font-size:100px !important
}
.swiper-button-next::after{
  font-size:100px !important
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a DIV and all children elements smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122333/make-a-div-and-all-children-elements-smaller)